# analogous of twitterbootstrap for mobile

Tags: css, mobile, web, responsive-design

**web:mobile::twitter-bootstrap:what**

as twiiter bootstrap offers funcationality to design sites keeping the best of the stuff and design practises in mind, do we have something for mobile as well.

I have already tried jquerymobile drag and drop and the themeroller, however i do have hell lot of issues while styling and customising them, i did struggle also finding a good tutorial which helped me to customize stuff, the way i wanted it to. Could anyone please let me know of any other boilerplate stuff, available primarily for designing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try their responsive version - it works fine on mobile devices (and tablets, and desktops, etc). Try this URL... http://ReactiveWebDesign.net